# Creating Desktop or terminal comands shortcuts to open a program

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

I recently installed Tor browser and in the site below the installation steps it says
to move to the downloaded folder via terminal and then type `./ start-tor-browser` to start tor, and it works. If I click the `start-tor-browser` file a text editor with code pops up..

How can I make a desktop shortcut or,if I can't, a shortcut for the commands to just type Tor(for example) in terminal instead of the two or three required commands every time I want to run tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install applet:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

Open it:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

[image]

Then the Create Launcher dialog box displays

Comment: i get "E: Unable to locate package –no-install-recommends
"

Comment: I think its a typo try --no-install-recommends also --create  Anyway I'll edit the answer